# Error Code: 1109 .Uknown table first_name in MULTI DELETE

Tags: mysql, database, compiler-errors, sql-delete, delete-row

Hi i have a problem in Mysql, how can i resolve this. Im getting unknown table first_name in MULTI DELETE.

```
DELETE personal_info.first_name, personal_info.last_name,       
        contact_info.email_address, 
        contact_info.cellphone_number,address_info.city,address_info.province,
        address_info.country
FROM personal_info
    INNER JOIN contact_info ON personal_info.id =  contact_info.personal_info_id
    INNER JOIN address_info ON personal_info.id= address_info.personal_info_id
WHERE personal_info.id = "1";
```

Comment: You dont delete columns you delete rows, So remove the column names

Comment: Hi. im still getting the same error.

Comment: Try `delete personal_info,contact_info , address_info from ....`

Comment: i tried to delete the column names in mysql but it is still getting the same error about MULTI DELETE